# I have multiple buttons/images in a form. How can I identify, in a Flask application, the one that was clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have this Flask app which holds several "buttons". I want to be able to react to every button with a different function.
Current HTML (see below) uses input with image type in order to have a post action upon clicking any of the images.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"/>
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="title">Automation-Rack Power Controller</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {% if led_status[0] == '1' %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS1_LED" src="/static/Red_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% else %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS1_LED" src="/static/Grey_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% endif %}
                        <input title="Power Socket 1" name="PS1" type="image" src="/static/TypeH_BlueUpSideDown.png" width="110" height="112">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {% if led_status[2] == '1' %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS3_LED" src="/static/Red_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% else %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS3_LED" src="/static/Grey_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% endif %}
                        <input title="Power Socket 3" name="PS3" type="image" src="/static/TypeH_BlueUpSideDown.png" width="110" height="112">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {% if led_status[4] == '1' %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS5_LED" src="/static/Red_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% else %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS5_LED" src="/static/Grey_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% endif %}
                       <input title="Power Socket 5" name="PS5" type="image" src="/static/TypeH_BlueUpSideDown.png" width="110" height="112">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {% if led_status[6] == '1' %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS7_LED" src="/static/Red_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% else %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS7_LED" src="/static/Grey_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% endif %}
                        <input title="Power Socket 7" name="PS7" type="image" src="/static/TypeH_BlueUpSideDown.png" width="110" height="112">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {% if led_status[1] == '1' %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS2_LED" src="/static/Red_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% else %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS2_LED" src="/static/Grey_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% endif %}
                        <input title="Power Socket 2" name="PS2" type="image" src="/static/TypeH_BluePowerSocket.png" width="110" height="112">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {% if led_status[3] == '1' %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS4_LED" src="/static/Red_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% else %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS4_LED" src="/static/Grey_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% endif %}
                        <input title="Power Socket 4" name="PS4" type="image" src="/static/TypeH_BluePowerSocket.png" width="110" height="112">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {% if led_status[5] == '1' %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS6_LED" src="/static/Red_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% else %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS6_LED" src="/static/Grey_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% endif %}
                        <input title="Power Socket 6" name="PS6" type="image" src="/static/TypeH_BluePowerSocket.png" width="110" height="112">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {% if led_status[7] == '1' %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS8_LED" src="/static/Red_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% else %}
                            <img class="led" id="PS8_LED" src="/static/Grey_10x10.png" width="10" height="10">
                        {% endif %}
                        <input title="Power Socket 8" name="PS8" type="image" src="/static/TypeH_BluePowerSocket.png" width="110" height="112">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

In my Flask app I am able to identify the POST request. But, unfortunately I can't identify the button that was clicked.
By the way, I also get the following error message on the screen after I click one of the buttons:
"Bad request, The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import telnetlib
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    current_status = Get_Power_State()
    # print(current_status)
    return render_template("home.html", led_status=current_status)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Greattttt')
        # print(request.form.get('input'))
        if request.form['PS1']:
            print('Power Socket 1')
        elif request.form['PS2']:
            print('Power Socket 2')
        elif request.form['PS3']:
            print('Power Socket 3')
        elif request.form['image'] == 'PS4':
            print('Power Socket 4')
        elif request.form['image'] == 'PS5':
            print('Power Socket 5')
        elif request.form['image'] == 'PS6':
            print('Power Socket 6')
        elif request.form['image'] == 'PS7':
            print('Power Socket 7')
        elif request.form['image'] == 'PS8':
            print('Power Socket 8')
        else:
            pass  # unknown
    # if request.method == "POST":
    #     Power_On_Off(2, 'off')
    #     print('Power 2 On')

    return '<h1>Clicked one of the buttons</h1>'


def Get_Power_State(Retries=5):
    '''
    Get the Power State of the 8 Power Sockets
    '''
    for attempt in range(Retries):
        try:
            on_off = telnetlib.Telnet('10.0.5.8', 2016)

            on_off.write(b"S00QLE\n")
            sleep(2)
            Power_State = on_off.read_very_eager().decode("utf-8")
            if Power_State == b'':
                raise ValueError("Power Switch didn't respond")
            # Index 3 = Socket 1, Index 4 = Socket 2 ... Index 10 = Socket 8
            Power_State = [Power_State[3], Power_State[4], Power_State[5], Power_State[6],
                           Power_State[7], Power_State[8], Power_State[9], Power_State[10]]

            on_off.close()
            break
        except socket.timeout:
            continue
        except EOFError:
            continue
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            continue

    # print(Power_State)

    return Power_State


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, threaded=True)
```

What am I doing wrong ? By the way, in order to serve several clients at the same time am I supposed to used the Flask threaded option ?

**EDIT**

I tried to replace the  with a  that includes an  but didn't even get a POST request as before when I clicked a button.
here is an example for the on button

```
<button title="Power Socket 1" name="PS1" value="Power1" type="button">
    <img src="/static/TypeH_BlueUpSideDown.png" width="110" height="112">
</button>
```

**FLASK CODE for catching the button value**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Greattttt')
        # print(request.form.get('input'))
        if request.form['button'] == 'Power1':
            print('Power Socket 1')
        elif request.form['button'] == 'Power2':
            print('Power Socket 2')
        elif request.form['button'] == 'Power3':
            print('Power Socket 3')
        elif request.form['button'] == 'Power4':
            print('Power Socket 4')
        elif request.form['button'] == 'Power5':
            print('Power Socket 5')
        elif request.form['button'] == 'Power6':
            print('Power Socket 6')
        elif request.form['button'] == 'Power7':
            print('Power Socket 7')
        elif request.form['button'] == 'Power8':
            print('Power Socket 8')
        else:
            pass  # unknown

     return '<h1>Clicked one of the buttons</h1>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<button>` in the html instead, because there you can put a `value` that gets included in the post data. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

**Don't** define `type=button` for the `<button>`, because like the docs say, the default type is `submit` and that works for the button to send the data:

> type
>
> The default behavior of the button. Possible values are:
>
> submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the
> default if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with
> a , or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value.
>
> reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values,
> like . (This behavior tends to annoy users.)
>
> button: The button has no default behavior, and does nothing when
> pressed by default. It can have client-side scripts listen to the
> element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

Alternatively, you can point the image inputs to go to different URLs, overriding the form action, but the `value` way is better and why the button inputs were made in the first place.

And no, you probably don't need threads with Flask, supposing your server responds to the requests quickly enough. The pages sit on the client side in the browser for your multiple users, so it's usually fine even if a million users open the page.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221665/discussion-on-answer-by-antont-i-have-multiple-buttons-images-in-a-form-how-can).